# angular-datatables in angular 6 , nested rows alignment issue and dtOptions are not loading

Tags: angular, nested, angular6, angular-datatables

```
  dtOptions = {
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    pageLength: 5,
    processing: true
  };
  mainData = [
    {'plus':'','ID':1,'FName':'AAA','SName':'A','Place':'ID'},
    {'plus':'','ID':2,'FName':'BBB','SName':'B','Place':'SG'},
    {'plus':'','ID':3,'FName':'CCC','SName':'C','Place':'HK'},
    {'plus':'','ID':4,'FName':'DDD','SName':'D','Place':'CN'}
  ];
  getRow(row){
    console.log("data",row);
    row.expand = true;
  }
```

[image: without error]
I am creating a table using angular-datatables in Angular 6. I am trying for nested tables like showing another table on expand of td.But the expanded row always adding at the top of the main table rows.

But I want show the nested table on expand of particular row like below the each row.
similar like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-create-drill-down-tables-using-this-library-1240.
attaching the screenshots for reference.
Please suggest me, what I am missing.

If I am adding like this

1. ```html
    <tbody>
                 <ng-template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="mainData" let-i="index">
                     <tr class="sub_{{i}}">
                         <td (click)="getRow(row)">
                           <i class="fa fa-plus" *ngIf="!row.expand"></i>
                           <i class="fa fa-minus" *ngIf="row.expand"></i>
                         </td>
                         <td>{{row.ID}}</td>
                         <td>{{row.FName}}</td>
                         <td>{{row.SName}}</td>
                         <td>{{row.Place}}</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr></tr>
                       <tr class="sub_{{i}} secondrow" *ngIf="row.expand">
                           <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-striped">
                             <thead>
                               <tr>
                                 <th>ID</th>
                                 <th>Name</th>
                               </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>
                               <tr>
                                 <td>1</td>
                                 <td>SSS</td>
                               </tr>
                             </tbody>
                           </table>
                       </tr>
                 </ng-template>  
             </tbody>
   ```

---

the nested row coming exactly below the row but dtOptions of main table is not loading.
[image: dtOptions loading issue]

Thank you

```html
  <div class="row" style="margin:0px;">
  <div class="col-md-12"><h6>Nested Table</h6></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>ID</td>
              <td>First Name</td>
              <td>Last Name</td>
              <td>Place</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <ng-template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="mainData" let-i="index">
                  <tr class="sub_{{i}}">
                      <td (click)="getRow(row)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></td>
                      <td>{{row.ID}}</td>
                      <td>{{row.FName}}</td>
                      <td>{{row.SName}}</td>
                      <td>{{row.Place}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="sub_{{i}} secondrow" *ngIf="row.expand">
                        <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-striped">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>SSS</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </tr>
              </ng-template>  
          </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: maintable [![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlgdJ.png)

Comment: How you are creating the new row. Please share your typescript code as well

Comment: @RavinSinghD updated the question.Please check.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-create-drill-down-tables-using-this-library-1240-cqmh8n?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

TS:

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  version = 'Angular: v' + VERSION.full;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  mainData = [];
  table;

  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  private datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      processing: true
    };
    this.mainData = [
      { 'plus': '', 'ID': 1, 'FName': 'AAA', 'SName': 'A', 'Place': 'ID' },
      { 'plus': '', 'ID': 2, 'FName': 'BBB', 'SName': 'B', 'Place': 'SG' },
      { 'plus': '', 'ID': 3, 'FName': 'CCC', 'SName': 'C', 'Place': 'HK' },
      { 'plus': '', 'ID': 4, 'FName': 'DDD', 'SName': 'D', 'Place': 'CN' },
      { 'plus': '', 'ID': 2, 'FName': 'BBB', 'SName': 'B', 'Place': 'SG' },
      { 'plus': '', 'ID': 3, 'FName': 'CCC', 'SName': 'C', 'Place': 'HK' },
      { 'plus': '', 'ID': 4, 'FName': 'DDD', 'SName': 'D', 'Place': 'CN' }
    ];

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then(table => {
      console.log(table);
      this.table = table
    });
  }

  addChildTable(rowInstance) {
    const row = this.table.row(rowInstance);
    const data = this.table.row(rowInstance).data()
    console.log(data);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
    }
    else {
      const childTable=this.getTable();
      row.child(childTable).show();
    }
  }

  getTable() {
    return `<table  class="table table-striped">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>1</td>
                              <td>SSS</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>`
  }


}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="margin:0px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h6>Nested Table</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table datatable  class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>Place</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let row of mainData;let i = index">
                    <tr #rowInstance>
            <td (click)=addChildTable(rowInstance)><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></td>
                        <td>{{row.ID}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.FName}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.SName}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.Place}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </ng-container>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This Way I already got the solution but I want do at Component side means in HTML.  Because the inside nested one is also again a Data Table and I have some functions like add and delete on each child row based on selection.Now I am able to do all those things like inside one as Data Table with actions and dtOptions also binding  except the main table dtOptions are not loading.Please help me.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-table

I have developed this plugin for angular to show expandable tables like below, you can see the complete configuration documentation in [NPM](https://npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-table) page

[image: Angular Tree Table]